# Dissociate YouTube channel from Google + account

Tags: youtube, google-plus, google-plus-pages

I created a Google+ Page with the wrong account. Now I am trying to delete this page but every time I try to do so I get that before deleting the page I have to disassociate my YouTube channel.

I have been trying to do that but I cant find the disassociate option on YouTube.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the [YouTube advanced account settings page](https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced) and "Move channel to different Google+ profile or page" to select the Google+ page/profile you want the YouTube account associated with.